# Adding functions to bison/jison calculator language

Tags: javascript, parsing, bison, jison

I'm trying to expand the [Jison calculator example](http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/) with some simple functions. I'm rather new to parsing and bison/jison, but this is a bit of what I have so far:

```
/* lexical grammar */
%lex

%{
  var funcs = {
    pow: function(a, b) { return Math.pow(a, b); },
    test: function(a) { return a*2; }
  }
%}

%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
[a-zA-Z]+             return 'NAME'
","                   return ','
"*"                   return '*'
"("                   return '('
")"                   return ')'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */
expressions
    : e EOF
      { return $1; }
    ;

expression_list
    : expression_list ',' e
    | e
    ;

e
    : e '*' e
        {$$ = $1*$3;}
    | '(' e ')'
        {$$ = $2;}
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    | NAME '(' expression_list ')'
        {$$ = funcs[$NAME]($expression_list);}
    ;
```

The problem is that functions are only getting one argument passed to them. For example:

```
test(2) -> 4
pow(2,3) -> null
```

In fact, if you `console.log` the arguments of `pow`, it appears `b` isn't even defined. Why isn't it parsing the whole expression list before sending it to the function?

Answer (score 4):

The following code does what you asked for. Salient points:

1. The rules for `expression_list` now build an actual list of values to be used with the functions being called.
2. The list built by `expression_list` are passed to `apply` so that they become the arguments of the function being called (`undefined` is there as the first argument to set the value of `this` to `undefined`).
3. I've added a `console.log` instruction to the actions for `expression` so that I'd see what is going on when I run the resulting parser at the command line.
4. I've moved the definition of `funcs` to the very start. Where it was jison was just not putting it in the right place in the final file.

Here's the final file:

```
%{var funcs = {
    pow: function(a, b) { return Math.pow(a, b); },
    test: function(a) { return a*2; }
  }
%}

/* lexical grammar */
%lex

%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
[a-zA-Z]+             return 'NAME'
","                   return ','
"*"                   return '*'
"("                   return '('
")"                   return ')'
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'
.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

%start expressions

%% /* language grammar */
expressions
    : e EOF
      { console.log($1); return $1; }
    ;

expression_list
    : expression_list ',' e
      { $$ = $1.concat([$3]); }
    | e
      { $$ = [$1]; }
    ;

e
    : e '*' e
        {$$ = $1*$3;}
    | '(' e ')'
        {$$ = $2;}
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    | NAME '(' expression_list ')'
        {$$ = funcs[$NAME].apply(undefined, $expression_list);}
    ;
```

Comment: Interesting. When I tried moving `funcs` there, the [online parser generator](http://zaach.github.io/jison/try/) gave me `funcs is not defined.` It also did that if I used `var funcs` instead of just `funcs`, which means I'm polluting the global scope. Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: For that specific problem I'd have to reread the docs I'm afraid. It has been a few months since I've written jison code on a daily basis. My working hypothesis is that where you had it, the code was local to the lexer. If the online tool works differently it may be that it has not been updated to the latest version. (It seems to be 0.4.13 whereas `npm install` installs 0.4.15.)

Comment: [Looks like declarations don't work when the parser is generated dynamically](https://github.com/zaach/jison/issues/188). That explains why it worked in npm.

Answer (score 1):

You need an action in the first production for `expression_list`. The default action just copies `$1` to `$$`, which means that the appended value is discarded.